# Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are well-ordered sets. Then $X + Y$ and $X \times Y$ are both well-ordered.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I have proved the first part in the title. I'd like to know if my reasoning is sound. If it is, then a similar argument for $X \times Y$ can be proved similarly.

Proof. We have
\begin{equation*}
X + Y = \left(X \times \left\{\boldsymbol{0}\right\}\right) \cup \left(Y \times \left\{\boldsymbol{1}\right\}\right).
\end{equation*}
Suppose $S \subseteq X + Y$ and $S \neq \emptyset$. Define the following set:
\begin{equation*}
A = \left\{ \boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}: \textrm{ there exists } t \in X \cup Y \textrm{ such that } \left(t,\boldsymbol{n}\right) \in S \right\}.
\end{equation*}
From $S \neq \emptyset$, it is clear that $A \subseteq \left\{\boldsymbol{0}, \boldsymbol{1}\right\}$ and $A \neq \emptyset$. As $\mathbb{N}$ is a well-ordered set, and $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, there is some $a_{0} \in A$ such that
\begin{equation*}
a_{0} = \min{A}.
\end{equation*}
It is obvious that $a_{0} = \boldsymbol{0}$ or $a_{0} = \boldsymbol{1}$.

If $a_{0} = \boldsymbol{0}$, define the following set:
\begin{equation*}
B_{0} = \left\{x \in X: \left(x,\boldsymbol{0}\right) \in S\right\}.
\end{equation*}
As $A \neq \emptyset$, we have $B_{0} \neq \emptyset$. As $B \subseteq X$ and $X$ is well-ordered, there is some $x_{0} \in X$ such that
\begin{equation*}
x_{0} = \min{B_{0}}.
\end{equation*}
We argue that $\left(x_{0},\boldsymbol{0}\right) = \min{S}$. If it is not, then there is some $x_{1} \in X$ such that $\left(x_{1},\boldsymbol{0}\right) \in S$ and $\left(x_{1},\boldsymbol{0}\right) < \left(x_{0},\boldsymbol{0}\right)$. This indicates that $x_{1} \in B_{0}$ and $x_{1} <_{X} x_{0}$, which contradicts that $x_{0} = \min{B}$. Thus, we have $\left(x_{0},\boldsymbol{0}\right) = \min{S}$.

If $a_{0} = \boldsymbol{1}$, then there is no $x \in X$ such that $\left(x,\boldsymbol{0}\right) \in S$ (otherwise, $a_{0} = \boldsymbol{0}$). Define the following set:
\begin{equation*}
B_{1} = \left\{y \in Y: \left(y,\boldsymbol{1}\right) \in S\right\}.
\end{equation*}
Again, $B_{1} \neq \emptyset$. As $Y$ is well-ordered and $B_{1} \subseteq Y$, there exists some $y_{0} \in Y$ such that
\begin{equation*}
y_{0} = \min{B_{1}}.
\end{equation*}
We argue that $\left(y_{0},\boldsymbol{1}\right) = \min{S}$. If not, then there exists $y_{1} \in Y$ such that $\left(y_{1},\boldsymbol{1}\right) \in S$ and $\left(y_{1},\boldsymbol{1}\right) < \left(y_{0},\boldsymbol{1}\right)$. However, this indicates that $y_{1} \in B_{1}$ and $y_{1} <_{Y} y_{0}$, contradicting that $y_{0} = \min{B_{1}}$. Thus, $\left(y_{0},\boldsymbol{1}\right) = \min{S}$.

As a result, $S$ is indeed of a minimum element. Due to the arbitrariness of $S$, we may conclude that $X + Y$ is well-ordered.

Comment: Your argument is right (given the standard way of inducing an ordering on $X + Y$ from orderings on $X$ and $Y$.  By using the standard identification of $X$ and $Y$ with subsets of $X + Y$, you could say it a bit more succinctly: let $\emptyset \neq S \subseteq X + Y$. If $S \subseteq Y$, then it has a minimum element in $Y$ and that is also a minimum element in $X + Y$, while if $S \cap X \neq \emptyset$, then the minimal element of $S \cap X$ in $X$ is also a minimal element in $X + Y$.

Comment: ... the last few words should read "is also a minimal element for $S$ in $X + Y$".

Answer (score 1):

Your argument looks OK, but I’d put it more succinctly: Let $X’ = X \times \{0\} \subseteq X+Y$ and $Y’ = Y \times \{1\} \subseteq X + Y$, and denote by $\pi$ the obvious maps from $X’$ onto $X$ and similarly for $Y’$.

If then $S$ is a non-empty subset of $X+Y$, there are two cases:

1. $S \cap X’$ is non-empty and let $x_0 = \min_X \pi[X’ \cap S]$ and check that $(x_0,0) = \min S$ in $X+Y$.
2. Not 1 implies $S \subseteq Y’$ and then let $y_0 = \min_Y \pi[ S]$ and check that $(y_0,1) = \min S$ in $X+Y$.

In either case $S$ has a minimum in $X+Y$ and we’re done.